# ¿Por qué no se recorre bien el arbol binario de busqueda?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

El problema es que solo puede agregar nodos al nivel 1 del arbol

- `BinarySearchTree`: clase arbol
- `root`: puntero de tipo nodo(la raiz del arbol)
- `TreeNode`: clase nodo
- `left`: puntero hacia la izquierda
- `right`: punteros hacia la derecha  ambos parte de la clase TreeNode
- `temp`: puntero temporal usado para recorrer el arbol

El código es el siguiente:

```
void BinarySearchTree::add(int value) {
if(root == nullptr) {
  root = new TreeNode(value);
} else {
    TreeNode* temp = root;
  while(temp->left != nullptr && temp->right != nullptr) {
    if(value > temp->value) {
      temp = temp->right;
    } else {
      temp = temp->left;
    }
  }
  if(value > temp->value) {
      if(temp->right == nullptr) {
       temp->right = new TreeNode(value);
      } else {
        temp->right = new TreeNode(value);
      }
  } else {
      if(temp->left == nullptr)
       temp->left = new TreeNode(value);
      else {
        temp->right = new TreeNode(value);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Pero ¿sabes que ya existe un BST? Se llama `std::set`...

Comment: Realmente mi conocimiento del lenguaje no es muy alto

Comment: Por eso se aprende... Para aprender, es bien implementar un BST. Solo: es mas complicado... ¿Que pasa si insertas 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (en este orden)? Sera un arbol degenerado. En ese caso, es necesario re-organizar el arbol. Hay bastante algoritmos, `std::set` (y `std::map`) normalmente implementan un [arbol rojo y negro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_rojo-negro)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Por qué obligas a que un nodo tenga que tener hijos a derecha e izquierda si, a lo sumo, a ti solo te interesa uno de los dos?

```
} else {
    TreeNode* temp = root;
  while(temp->left != nullptr && temp->right != nullptr) { // <---
```

Ese `while`, directamente, sobra. Lo que tienes que hacer es localizar un nodo padre donde encajar tu nodo actual. Si no hay padre es porque el árbol está vacío, en cuyo caso el nuevo nodo pasa a ser el raiz.

Es decir, tu tienes que ir navegando por el árbol. En cada iteración comparas el valor a insertar con el del nodo. Esta comparación te puede llevar por tres caminos:

- Ambos valores son iguales: Ya existe un nodo en el árbol con el valor pedido, lo normal aquí es no hacer nada.
- El valor a insertar es mayor que el del nodo: En este caso debemos mirar si el nodo actual tiene un nodo a la derecha. Si lo tiene nos movemos a ese nodo y pasamos a la siguiente iteración... si no tiene nodo derecho ya hemos encontrado la posición en la que debemos ubicar el nuevo nodo.
- El valor a insertar es menor que el del nodo: Lo mismo que en el caso anterior pero aplicado al lado derecho.

Dicho con código podría quedar así:

```
void BinarySearchTree::add(int value)
{
  if(root == nullptr) {
    root = new TreeNode(value);
  } else {
    TreeNode* temp = root;

    while( true )
    {
      if( temp->value == value )
          return; // Ya existe un nodo con ese valor

      if( temp->value > value )
      {
         if( temp->right == nullptr )
         {
           temp->right = new TreeNode(value);
           break;
         }
         else
           temp = temp->right;
      }
      else
      {
         if( temp->left == nullptr )
         {
           temp->left = new TreeNode(value);
           break;
         }
         else
           temp = temp->left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no tenia idea de como parar el bucle por lo que pensé que si ambos hijos del nodo padre eran nulos querian decir que me encontraba en el ultimo por lo que solo debia agregar el hijo cuando llegaba al final del ciclo